# Huge, inconsistent delay when accessing JSON data from a web address

Tags: c#, json, http-headers, httpclient

I'm trying to get JSON data from websites (like themoviedb.org).  I can successfully retrieve the data, but sometimes when I do this there is a whopping delay that can last over a minute or I get a connection failed message (server timeout?).  When this happens the problem persists for the next few hours - but I can try later the same evening and the same code works almost instantly!

*EDIT: I should also mention that when the first delay is finally over all other requests are then carried out instantly - it's just the first request that causes a big hold-up.  When I restart the app the delay happens all over again.*

This doesn't appear to affect any other internet connection on my PC - and I can always manually copy and paste the same request into my browser for instant JSON results.  Something about my app or my Visual Studio 2015 setup is allowing this random delay to keep cropping up.

Here is the code for the app:

```
    public static HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    }

    private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;
        string url = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/person?api_key=" + theMovieDbKey + "&query=%22Hanks%22";
        HttpResponseMessage response = await Client.GetAsync(url);
        string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
        MessageBox.Show(content);
    }
```

So far I've tried without success:

- Switching from WebClient to HttpClient
- Changing security protocols.
- Disabling proxies.
- Disabling diagnostic tools.

The second item on this Fiddler screen shows some info:

[image: Fiddler results]

And here are the headers:

[image: Fiddler headers]

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I just don't know what is causing this.

EDIT: The headers from a successful browser request are:

[image]

Comment: Did you try to get a response using browser and compare the results. I don't think that your problem is related to json, it seems to be a connection ussue

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Yes I tried using a browser and the response is always instant, and yeah it must be a connection issue - something to do with sockets not becoming available or something?  I don't know much about that tbh.

Comment: You can start from looking a request and response headers and compare them with your app

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Well I've now added a screenshot of a successful browser headers, but I'm afraid it doesn't mean much to me.  Interestingly, I couldn't connect to the internet at all just now and I had to restart my computer (As though my failed tests caused a blockage ALL other connections too).  Does this help at all?

Comment: Fiddler can block a web traffic, if not properly configured or capture https

Comment: None of this helps me understand why this problem occurs.  Surely the fact that it happens at random times offers some sort of clue?  Also, I should mention that when the delay is finally over, all subsequent request tasks are carried out very quickly and as expected - but if restart the app I have to get past the delay all over again.

Comment: How frequent are your requests? A few times an hour? Hundreds of times a second? Something in between?

Comment: It's normally 2 requests at a time (the first to get an ID number that I use to create the more useful second request immediately after).  But with all the testing I'm doing this happens about 10 - 20 times in the space of an hour to pull data on different movies and / or actors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with help from someone on another site.  It turns out that my server requests were all using IPv6 protocols which can lead to all sorts of random delays if your DNS setup isn't perfect.  Forcing my app to use IPv4 protocols fixed the issue immediately.

**Note that requests to a HTTPS host require request headers to work correctly.**

Here is the code that worked for me, I hope it helps someone else:

```
    public static HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Set required security protocols.
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

        // Set Host header required for HTTPS connections.
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Host", "api.themoviedb.org");
    }

    private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;

        // Get DNS entries for the host.
        Uri uri = new Uri("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/person?api_key=" + theMovieDbKey + "&query=%22Hanks%22");
        var hostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(uri.Host);

        // Get IPv4 address
        var ip4 = hostEntry.AddressList.First(addr => addr.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);

        // Build URI with numeric IPv4
        var uriBuilderIP4 = new UriBuilder(uri);
        uriBuilderIP4.Host = ip4.ToString();
        var uri4 = uriBuilderIP4.Uri;

        // Retrieve asynchronous string from specified URI.
        HttpResponseMessage response = await Client.GetAsync(uri4);
        string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = null;
        MessageBox.Show(content);
    }
```